# Editting text created using text tool

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a text field created using the Flash's Text Tool I set it to dynamic.
Is it possible to edit that text using AS3? If yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *all* the properties of the textfield. So

both

```
textfield.text
```

and

```
textfield.htmlText
```

will work.

If the textfield is too small, use the `autoSize` property:

```
textfield.autoSize = "left";
textfield.htmlText = "<b>hello,\nworld</b>";
```

will output:

```
hello,
world
```

with bold text.

You can also change the `multiline` property, the `wordWrap`, `background` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Click the text field and set an **instance name** for it in the **properties** panel. From here you can access the text field via:

```
your_instance_name
```

So to set the text is as easy as:

```
your_instance_name.text = "your new text";
```